# Howto save only SQLPlus errors to file (called from powershell)

Tags: oracle, powershell, scripting, sqlplus

I'm calling SQLPlus from powershell and I'm trying to show the user the error messages if something went wrong. If there are no issues, the script should just continue.

This is what I use

```
sqlplus -S $user/$user@$server @$file
```

For sqlcmd I managed to do it this way:

```
sqlcmd -S $serverLower -U $user -P $user -d $user -i $file -r1 2>errors.txt 1>$null
if (CheckIfFileExistsAndNotEmpty errors.txt)
    {
    get-content errors.txt | write-host
    }
```

The option -r set to one will output the errors, and 2>errors.txt writes them to file.

I want something similar for SQLPlus, if possible without using SPOOL (the scripts executed by sqlplus are user defined and I would like it if I should not change them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found myself:

```
    AddAsFirstLine $file "SPOOL $errorfilepath"
    Add-Content -Path $file -Value "SPOOL off"
    sqlplus -S $user/$user@$server @$file 1>$null

    $errors = Select-String -Path $errorfilepath -Pattern "(SP2|ORA|Msg.*Level.*State.*Server.*Line|SQLConverter-Error:|Init-Error:|Invalid.filename)"
    Set-Content -Path errors.txt $errors
    Remove-Item $errorfilepath -Force | Out-Null
    }

    if (CheckIfFileExistsAndNotEmpty errors.txt)
    {
        Write-Host "Error while executing script"
        get-content errors.txt | write-host
    }
```

AddAsFirstLine and CheckIfFileExistsAndNotEmpty are functions declared by me.